# Aptana 3.5 not show SVN Toolbar

Tags: svn, aptana

After update from Aptana 3.4.2 to 3.5.0, i can't see SVN Buttons on Toolbar
I already checked SVN in Toolbar Visibility.

I try create new Workspace then SVN Toolbar show again.

What happen with my Workspace or Aptana? and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade to 3.4.2 since 3.5 was removed